# How to Send an Array of Multiple Selects with Multiple Values to PHP

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, request

Currently I have a base table where the row structure is like so:

```
<td>
    <select class="form-control chargeType" name="charge_type[]">
        <option value="">Please Select</option>
        @foreach($charges as $c)
            <option value="{{$c->id}}">
                {{$c->name}} (${{$c->amount}})
            </option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</td>
<td>
    <select class="form-control lotSelector" name="lot[]" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="">Please Select</option>
        @foreach($lots as $l)
            <option value="{{$l->id}}">
                {{$l->block_id}}-{{$l->section->section_number}}-{{$l->lot_number}}
            </option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</td>
```

But you have the ability to add additional copies of the same row. Currently if I POST this request, it splits the multiple values up individually, and not into the same index of the field they are supposed to be grouped in.

For example:

```
lot => [
    0 => "1"
    1 => "4"
    2 => "5"
    3 => "10"
]
```

When in reality it should be:

```
lot => [
    0 => ["1","4","5"]
    1 => ["10"]
]
```

I would appreciate any and all help. Thanks.

Comment: What's the logic to put "10" into a separated index?

Comment: If I added a second row of the exact same first row (like with a table of fields), the second index is the second select box.

Comment: You mean another `<select>` element?

Comment: Correct, of the same structure that has been copied using jQuery.

Comment: So just change the name to `lot[0][]`, `lot[1][]` and so on. Use javascript to manipulate the index.